# Não permitir que o comando curl faça o download do meu site inteiro. É possível?

Tags: html, libcurl

Como eu poderia alterar meu código HTML, para que quando faça uma consulta com `curl` não traga o site inteiro HTML para o console? Uma falha de segurança que não sei resolver no meu site pessoal que estou criando, alguém pode ajudar por favor?

No código `$ curl http://www.uol.com.br` a resposta é:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.uol.com.br/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Na Amazon, `$ curl http://amazon.com` a resposta é:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>Server</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando consulto o site pessoal que estou criando, so html, css e js, e armazenei num S3 bucket da AWS, baixa o site inteiro, como posso resolver isso? Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que a url que tentou acessar tem um redirect, e o `curl` retornou essa primeira resposta que encontrou, sem tratar esse redirect.

Tenta a url correta, por exemplo: `curl https://www.amazon.com/`, ou ainda usar o parâmetro L para tratar os redirects: `curl -L http://amazon.com` e vai ver que funciona.

Acho que está entendendo errado o conceito, pra que quer impedir de devovler o response do html do site, para um request correto?
`curl` é apenas um client, poderia ser o navegador, e ia então impedir que alguém tivesse acesso ao teu site.

Além disso, o `curl` não vai fazer "download do seu site interiro", só var retorar o tiver na url, igual se fosse aberta no navegador.

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, fiquei preocupado somente com seguranca, fiz um website simples e hospedei na AWS num S3 bucket, mas coloquei TLS e habilitei HTTPS com um certificado deles mesmo usando cloudfront, acho que vai ficar desse jeito mesmo por enquanto. Obrigado pelo feedback.

Answer (score -2):

O `curl` sempre retorna o HTML do site. O que você está vendo no seu teste é um redirecionamento do `http` para `https`. Caso altere esses seus testes para fazer o request com `https` no lugar de `http` pegará o html que você espera. ex: `curl https://www.uol.com.br`.

Note que o mesmo também pode ocorrer para incluir ou remover `www`, a barra no final e outras coisas. Para certificar-se, abra o site em questão no seu navegador e verifique o endereço que aparece (ou siga o "rastro" pela resposta do `curl`).

Quanto à primeira pergunta, não é possível "proteger" o HTML, CSS ou JS do seu site. Entretanto é possível dificultar o entendimento e a leitura do mesmo, mas é o tipo de coisa que não faz muito sentido e inclusive costuma ser motivo de piada (o Scott Hanselman, inclusive, fez essa piada na abertura do NDC Porto 2020).

Caso seja mesmo o objetivo, é possível diferenciar a resposta do servidor quando se usa um navegador ou outro, ou até mesmo um programa que não seja um navegador. Em geral se faz isso pelos headers, entretanto, não serve como "proteção", uma vez que podem ser adicionados os headers para se passar por um navegador.

Outra possibilidade é não ter somente uma "base" no HTML original e carregar todo o site com JS, substituindo o conteúdo do `<body>`, por exemplo. Um bom exemplo disso são os sites gerados na plataforma WIX.

Um exemplo outro exemplo onde o curl não retorna o esperado é o amazon.com, onde o resultado de `curl https://www.amazon.com/` é a imagem abaixo.

[image: resultado do curl à amazon.com]

Comment: "Isso pode ser feito pelo user-agent" - só se for pra espantar curioso. Não tem como diferenciar de um browser pelo user-agent pelo simples fato de que basta por um igual do browser ao usar o cURL. A única resposta válida para essa pergunta seria "Não tem como" (e poderia ser complementada com "quase certeza que não tem motivo também"). SE a pessoa quiser evitar scrap de dados, pode fazer outras coisas para minimizar automação (colocar um captcha, por exemplo), mas realmente são poucos casos de uso que justificam.

Comment: Complementarei a resposta @Bacco, uma vez que esqueci de responder a 1a pergunta e respondi somente a parte do curl ao uol e Amazon. E como vc pode ver no exemplo da Amazon, não só é possível, como eles o fizeram. Não testei todas as possibilidades para confirmar como fizeram.

Comment: Aí é falha no teste, e não proteção da Amazon. Experimente por os headers iguais os de um navegador comum e verá o mesmo source que no browser (que não vai ter muita graça pq é cheio de JS, mas será o mesmo).

Comment: Sim, e as 2 questões foram respondidas. E obrigado por comentar. Quando não há comentários é impossível saber o que está mal na resposta.

Comment: De qualquer forma, só pra constar, esses negativos aí não são meus. Eu tou comentando pra apontar os problemas apenas. O problema maior mesmo é a premissa da pergunta.

Comment: obrigado de qualquer forma. complementarei a resposta com mais alguns comentários :)

Comment: Dias, obrigado pela forca e pela resposta bem detalhada, sou nubao em webpage, fiz um negocio caseiro, e hospedei na AWS, vou estudar mais e dar um tapa no website, acho que vou usar o wordpress. E' isso que preciso fazer, dar uma enganada no curl quando usa o console do linux, vou pesquisar mais a respeito, obrigado pela forca.